# how to convert multiple format of dates into only one format using java

Tags: java

from the database postgressql i'm getting date sometime date in different different forlamts like  "2015-11-26 09:30:10","2015-11-26 09:30:10.080","2015-11-26 09:30:10.000" now i want to convert all format as only this format 22/01/2018 how to do in java.

```
    try {
        Date theDate1 = new Date("JAN 13,2014 09:15");
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String temp = format1.format(theDate1);
        System.out.println("Hello, World! " + temp);
    } catch (Exception e {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

i got output as Hello, World !13 / 01 / 2014 but when i tried

```
    try {
        Date theDate1 = new Date("2017-11-27 00:00:00");
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String temp = format1.format(theDate1);
        System.out.println("Hello, World! " + temp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

then i got java.lang.IllegalArgumentExceptionhow to solve this problem

Comment: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and take the time to format your question readably. Use the preview underneath the editor box so you can check that the post will be readable.

Comment: Do you use JDBC? Than use [`ResultSet.getTimestamp(int columnIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-int-) to receive the Date from the database. After this you can format the Date with a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Edwardth The `java.sql.Timestamp` Class is now legacy, supplanted by use of `java.time.Instant` with JDBC 4.2 and later. `Instant instant  = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;` Likewise, `SimpleDateFormat` is supplanted by `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String text = "JAN 13,2014 09:15";
    String patternst = "\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternst);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    String data = "";
    while (matcher.find()) {
        data = matcher.group(0);
    }
    try {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(data.split("-")[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(data.split("-")[1]);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(data.split("-")[2]);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        Date theDate1 = cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String temp = format1.format(theDate1);
        System.out.println("Hello, World! " + temp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Date theDate1 = new Date(text);
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String temp = format1.format(theDate1);
        System.out.println("Hello, World! " + temp);
    }
```

Comment: The troublesome date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the modern `java.time` classes. Their use today is ill-advised.