# Date format is not comming properly

Tags: java

When I'm passing text as like this `13/01/2014` and `13-01-2014`

```
String text = "JAN 13,2014 09:15";
String patternst = "\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternst);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
String data = "";
while (matcher.find()) {
    data = matcher.group(0);
}
try {
    int year = Integer.parseInt(data.split("-")[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(data.split("-")[1]);
    int day = Integer.parseInt(data.split("-")[2]);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    Date theDate1 = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new ("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String temp = format1.format(theDate1);
    System.out.println("Hello, World! " + temp);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Date theDate1 = new Date(text);
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String temp = format1.format(theDate1);
    System.out.println("Hello, World! " + temp);
}
```

then I'm getting the error like this `Exception in thread "main java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` otherwise some other output is comming how to solve this problem i want date format always `dd/MM/yyyy` if text is `23/01/2017` or `13-01-2014` or `13-01-2015.00`, `13-01-2014.567` or `JAN 13,2014 09:15`

Comment: please format your code

Comment: How is this question related to your older question?: [how to convert multiple format of dates into only one format using java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48382668/4503858)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert multiple format of dates into only one format using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382668/how-to-convert-multiple-format-of-dates-into-only-one-format-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid the use of classes and methods which are marked as `@Deprecated` like `new Date(String s)`.

Now the correct way to parse a `Date` is with [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), so you need to create a proper pattern to parse the Date.

In your case you have the text `JAN 13,2014 09:15` the matching pattern would be `MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm`.

And here is a code sample how to use it:

```
try {
    String pattern = "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm";
    String text = "JAN 13,2014 13:15";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    Date date = format.parse(text);

    // Directly output the date
    System.out.println(date);

    // Output the date with another pattern
    String pattern2 = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern2);
    System.out.println(format2.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

When you have to parse dates in multiply different formats you can create an array with the different possible pattern:

```
public static Date parse(String text) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    // The detaild pattern must be before the vague
    String[] pattern = {
            "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm",
            "MMM dd,yyyy",
            "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "dd/MM/yyyy",
            "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "dd-MM-yyyy",
        };

    for(String p : pattern) {
        try {
            format.applyPattern(p);
            return format.parse(text); 
        } catch (ParseException ignore) {
        }
    }

    return null; // or Throw an Exception
}
```

This should only be used when you need to handle user-inputs. (Also i would recommend to restrict the user-input to only provide the desired format.)